# Storing output of nested loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, output

I am new to R but trying desperately to learn the ropes. In fact I feel a little stupid asking this question as I have gone through a number of similar problems but have not been able to get the desired results. My code is as shown below :

```
## Initializing Parameters

fstart <- 960   ## Start frequency in MHz
fstop <- 1240   ## Stop Frequency In MHz
bw <- 5.44      ## IF Bandwidth in MHz
offset <- 100   ## Max. Variation in TOD in milliseconds
f_dwell <- 1    ## Time spent on each search frequency in millisecond
iterations <- 100 ## No. of iterations to run

## No. of possible frequencies 

f <- seq((fstart + bw/2), (fstop - bw/2), by=bw)

## Initializing the frequency table

freq_table <- matrix (NA, nrow=(2*offset +1), ncol=offset)

## Fill frequency table row wise with random values of possible frequencies

for (i in 1:(2*offset + 1)){

row_value <- c(sample(f), sample(f, offset-length(f)))
freq_table[i, ] <- row_value
}

## Assign a row from freq_table to unknown node

unknown_node <- freq_table[sample(1:(2*offset + 1), 1), ]
t = numeric(iterations)
## Calculate number of repetitions of frequencies
for(k in 1:iterations){
for(j in 1:offset){

    y <- (sort(table(freq_table[, j]), decreasing=TRUE))
    x <- as.vector(y)       ## Number of repetitions of each frequency
    y <- names(y)

## Search Frequencies

sf1 <- as.numeric(y[1])
sf2 <- as.numeric(y[2])

    if (unknown_node[j] == sf1){
    t[k] <- ((j-1)*f_dwell)*2 + f_dwell
break
    }
    else {
  if (unknown_node[j] == sf2){
    t[k] <- ((j-1)*f_dwell)*2 + 2*f_dwell
    break
    }
    }
## Delete rows from freq_table that have sf1 & sf2

freq_table <- subset(freq_table, freq_table[, 1]!=sf1 & freq_table[, 1]!=sf2 )
}

}

print(t)
```

If I run this without the k for loop, I get different values of variable t every time. However, I wanted to run the inner for loop iteratively and get a vector of t values each time the inner for loop runs. I do get the length of t as 100, but the values are repeating. The first few values (2 0r 3 or sometimes 4) are different, but the rest keep repeating. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Ok, figured out myself post some debugging in RStudio. For values to change every time I run the simulation, unknown_node also needs to be within the k for loop. And since number of rows of freq_table are decreasing, unknown_node <- freq_table[sample(1:a[1], 1), ] where a <- dim(freq_table)